# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not re.Pattern

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

When running the following code

```
sneaker_info.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'td' and re.compile('Size') in tag.text)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not re.Pattern
```

I know that I can use
`sneaker_info.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'td' and 'Size' in tag.text)`
but I would like to use a regex pattern for extracting the info needed.
Is there a way to get around this error?

P.S I also can't use `sneaker_info.find('td', string=re.compile(r'Size'))` on this piece of HTML

Comment: try using str(re.compile(r'Size'))

Comment: @Luiz what do you think that would do?

Comment: convert to a string, just a guess to try to help

Answer (score 2):

Your regex object made by `re.compile()` isn't compatible with the `in` keyword for strings as it expects to receive a string not a regex object.

You can do `"sm" in "small" => true` but not `1 in "small"`.

You probably want something like this:

```
re.compile('Size').search(tag.text)
```

Checkout the regex docs for more here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Option 2:
You don't actually need a regex here. It's overkill for simple substring matching.
You can also more simply do

```py
"Size" in tag.text
```

Comment: I think they'd want to use `search()` rather than `match()` for behavior equivalent to `in`, based on my reading of the docs.

Comment: @DaveCosta thanks, you are correct updated.

Comment: Thanks!!! You really helped me out here